# Angular not detecting changes in template

Tags: html, angular, typescript, deployment

When chaning something in the template file of the component (html) the webbrowser doesnt reload, but when I edit something in the typescript and save the changes the webbroser does. Currently I need to use the save action in the typescript (not depending on doing changes on it or not) in order to make the browser reload to show the html changes.

Angular version:

```
Angular CLI: 12.1.1
Node: 14.16.0
Package Manager: npm 7.19.1
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 12.1.1
... animations, cdk, cli, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core
... forms, material, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1201.1
@angular-devkit/build-angular   12.1.1
@angular-devkit/core            12.1.1
@angular-devkit/schematics      12.1.1
@ngtools/webpack                12.1.1
@schematics/angular             12.1.1
rxjs                            7.1.0
typescript                      4.3.5
```

tsconfig.json:

```
/* To learn more about this file see: https://angular.io/config/tsconfig. */
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "module": "es2020",
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "project",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~10.2.4",
    "@angular/common": "~10.2.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "~10.2.4",
    "@angular/core": "~10.2.4",
    "@angular/forms": "~10.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~10.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~10.2.4",
    "@angular/router": "~10.2.4",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1002.3",
    "@angular/cli": "~10.2.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~10.2.4",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~5.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~4.0.2"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you just need to set `"compileOnSave"` to be equal to `true` in your `tsconfig.json` file.

Comment: Would be nice. I have already tried that before your reputation, but it didnt work